# Inter-App Communication for sandboxed swift app on macOS

Tags: swift, cocoa, ipc, appstore-sandbox, nsxpcconnection

I'm building a sandboxed macOS app with Swift, which contains a child app inside.

What I want to implement is:

- Parent can launch multiple child apps
- Parent send different content to each child app to show
- Both parent and child app have their own UIs.

Implementation way I've been thinking about:

**Distributed Notification**

Distributed notification with user info objects are denied by sandbox.

**CFMessagePort**

It requires both parent and child app are in the same app group, and signed with proper provision profiles. But on Xcode it is always `None required` on the provision profile settings so nowhere to change the settings.
Besides, there is no documents or posts explaining how to use CFMessagePort in Swift. I tried the code below but it crashes everytime as it's denied by sandbox.

```
let portName = "{team_identifier}.{app_group_identifier}.{port_name}"
let remote = CFMessagePortCreateRemote(nil, portName as CFString)
var returnData: Unmanaged<CFData>? = nil
if kCFMessagePortSuccess == CFMessagePortSendRequest(remote, 0, data as CFData, 1, 1, CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue, &returnData) && nil != returnData {
    
}
```

**NSXPCConnection**

I don`t think XPC works for this situation, as XPC is designed to communicate between a service running invisible and a client app, while the service is bundled into the app. I doubt it would work for the parent-child model.

---

So, is there any better way to achieve my target? I feel I should go with CFMessagePort but I also need some more help on how to use it with Swift. Thanks!

Comment: NSXPCConnection should be perfect for this. What problems are you seeing?

Comment: Do you have a developer account?

Comment: @RobNapier I do lack knowledge about XPC. As I understand, XPC service itself  not visible for enduser, and even Parent app contains a XPC bundle, the parent shouldn't be able to use the XPC service to initiate a message send request to several child apps. Or can you give me a structure example that how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @WikipediaBrown Yes I do have a developer account for years and have other apps on Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to use Apple Events, as I do. Sandboxed apps can receive and send Apple Events to themselves by default, but they cannot send Apple Events to other applications. However, they can send Apple Events if

> "you request a **scripting-targets** entitlement or an **apple-events
> temporary exception** entitlement. In the same way, regardless of
> whether your app is sandboxed, any external sandboxed app that
> attempts to interact with your app must also request the appropriate
> entitlements to do so."

You can read all about it on the Technical Q&A note [QA1888](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1888/_index.html).

I would also recommend that you check this [tutorial](https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/) to handle Apple Events in a sandboxed app and this tutorial ([part 1](https://medium.com/@an23lm/applescript-and-swift-meant-to-be-ehhh-cbe03883a59) and [part 2](https://medium.com/@an23lm/applescript-and-swift-part-2-passing-parameters-ea566c1d1a85)) how to handle the foundation classes you can use to build Apple Events in Swift.

If you want a more in-depth explanation and including sample code (however, it is mostly in C), you can refer to Apple's references pages, namely:

- [Apple Event Manager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/apple_event_manager)
- [AppleScript Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000156i) (explains in
  detail macOS scripting architecture)
- [Apple Events Programming
  Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/intro_aepg/intro_aepg.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001449) (full reference for building, sending and receiving Apple
  Events)

If you run into trouble, let us know as I use this old but proven technology to handle most IPC between my main app and its helpers.